# Ruby cant append to JSON file

Tags: arrays, json, ruby, hash

I am trying to append a JSON object to an existing JSON file. I used StackOverflow and Google but i cant find my answer. Here is my code:

```
json = File.read(File.join( File.dirname(__FILE__),"configs/#{enviroment}.json"))

rb_hash = JSON.parse(json);

rb_hash["searchExamples"] << { name: "John", long: 20, lat: 45 }

rb_hash.to_json
```

but i get the error:

```
undefined method `<<' for #<Hash:0x007ffa93124bd0> (NoMethodError)
Did you mean?  <
```

Comment: The interpreter tells the truth. The [`<<` method](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/index.html#methods) is defined only for the classes [`Array`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Array.html), [`IO`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/IO.html), [`Integer`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Integer.html), [`Queue`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Queue.html), [`SizedQueue`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/SizedQueue.html) and [`String`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/String.html). And [`Hash`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Hash.html) doesn't extend any of them.

Comment: @Azeem How does your suggestion help the method `<<` not being undefined in class [`Hash`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Hash.html) any more?

Comment: The method you are looking for is [`Hash#merge!`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Hash.html#method-i-merge-21).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`rb_hash["searchExamples"]` is a hash and as @axiac said there is no `<<` method on Hash class in ruby. Use [Hash#merge](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Hash.html#method-i-merge) to concatenate two hashes:

```
json = File.read(File.join( File.dirname(__FILE__),"configs/#{enviroment}.json"))

rb_hash = JSON.parse(json);
rb_hash["searchExamples"] = rb_hash["searchExamples"].merge({ name: "John", long: 20, lat: 45 })
# or rb_hash["searchExamples"].merge!({ name: "John", long: 20, lat: 45 })

File.write(File.join( File.dirname(__FILE__),"configs/#{enviroment}.json"), rb_hash.to_json)
```

Also you might want to use pretty generate gems like [NeatJSON](https://github.com/Phrogz/NeatJSON) or [JSON#pretty_generate](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/json/rdoc/JSON.html#method-i-pretty_generate) for better json output in your file

Comment: what does the ! mark mean in this instance? and once i merged the two hashes how do i update the file? Sorry im relatively new to ruby

Comment: `!` on method means that this method gonna mutate initial object/data. Its a convention in ruby. On the other hand methods without `!` like [Hash#merge](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Hash.html#method-i-merge) will return you new object with changes applied to it and initial one will stay intact.

Comment: Overall its a good practise to avoid mutations like that in your code

Comment: ah okay cool, so now the hash is updated why do i not see it in the file? Once i get it working I can mark the answer correct thanks so much

Comment: because you should write to a file a new json?

Comment: `File.write(File.join( File.dirname(__FILE__),"configs/#{enviroment}.json"), rb_hash.to_json)`

Comment: I tried that already it didnt work, the new Object was not added and also it adds => instead of colons making the json file invalid

Comment: did you forgot to call `.to_json` on `rb_hash`? Look at my code above. If not update your question with the code that is not working

Comment: heres my code on pastebin https://pastebin.com/zmR0Hbxb . the object John is not added anywhere to my json

Comment: As I said Hash#merge does not mutate initial object. In your case its `rb_hash["searchExamples"]`

Comment: Also you might want to use pretty generate gems like [NeatJSON](https://github.com/Phrogz/NeatJSON) or [JSON#pretty_generate](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/json/rdoc/JSON.html#method-i-pretty_generate) for better json output in your file

Comment: Okay ill do that, I just realised actually that the oriiginal JSON file gets deleted and the new JSON file is just searchExamples, my goal was to append to the existing jSON file searchExample object

Comment: Remove `.to_json` call if you are using `JSON.pretty_generate`. Like that `JSON.pretty_generate(rb_hash)`